# how to make the whole webpage look smaller (just like zoom out function of chrome) using CSS or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Hi I am a beginner in web dev and I built a page on my ultra-wide 3k display without realizing everything looks so big on regular sized displays. But when I use zoom function in chrome to reduce it to 75% then it looks perfectly fine. Is there anyway to achieve this with css or js?

Answer (score 0):

Wow you have a lot to learn my friend

Here are some things to get you started

- [Responsive Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)
- [Mobile Responsive Design](http://www.studiopress.com/beginners-guide-responsive-design/)
- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Screen sizes and break points for responsive design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design)
- [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest :

Either use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or any such framework so that you don't have to worry much about the sizing of your page on different devices.

Read : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Answer (score 0):

you have to use media queries, this one has the newest all together, just copy it and put in your css code [gist.github.com/needim/d15fdc2ac133d8078f7c](http://gist.github.com/needim/d15fdc2ac133d8078f7c)